# Automatically extend class with methods coming from another module

Tags: python, decorator

Immagine that I have defined several **methods acting on an object**, and I have two or more different classes that **cannot** inherit from the same parent, having an instance of that object. I want to **automatically add all the methods to the two classes**, removing the first argument (the object) and replacing it with the instance owned by the class.

Is there a way to do it?

I am sure my question is not clear, so I try to give a super simplified settings. to keep things simple the object is just a list. I hope that after the example my objective is clear! Thanks in advance for your time.

```python
# I define some methods acting on an object (just 2 useless methods acting on a list in this example)
def get_avg(input_list):
    return sum(input_list) / len(input_list)


def multiply_elements(input_list, factor):
    return [i * factor for i in input_list]
```

Then we have 2 different classes, both have an instance of our object (the list)

```python
class A:
    list_of_apples = []

    def get_list_of_apples(self):
        return self.list_of_apples


class B:
    """Totally different class from A(pples), also containing a list"""
    list_of_bears = []

    def get_list_of_bears(self):
        return self.list_of_bears
```

Now, to call a "list" method on the lists owned by A and B instances, I would need to do the following:

```python
b = B()
get_avg(b.get_list_of_bears())
```

My goal, instead, is to automatically define some wrappers (as the following ones) which would allow me to call list methods directly from instances of A and B. Here there is an example for B:

```python
class B:
    """Totally different class from A(pples), but containing a list"""
    list_of_bears = []

    def get_list_of_bears(self):
        return self.list_of_bears

    def get_avg(self):
        return get_avg(self.list_of_bears)

    def multiply_elements(self, factor):
        return multiply_elements(self.list_of_bears, factor)
```

With the extended class, I can simply do:

```python
b = B()
b.get_avg()
b.multiply_elements(factor=10)
```

I would like to automatically extend A and B.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your classes cannot inherit from a common ancestor but one solution I can think of is to make the ancestor **dynamically**:

```
def make_ancestor():
    class Temp:
        def get_avg(self):
            input_list = getattr(self, self.list_name)
            return sum(input_list) / len(input_list)
        def multiply_elements(self, factor):
            input_list = getattr(self, self.list_name)
            return [i * factor for i in input_list]
    return Temp


class A(make_ancestor()):
    list_of_apples = []
    list_name = 'list_of_apples'
    def get_list_of_apples(self):
        return self.list_of_apples


class B(make_ancestor()):
    list_of_bears = []
    list_name = 'list_of_bears'
    def get_list_of_bears(self):
        return self.list_of_bears
```

Now since the parent classes are being generated dynamically your child classes don't inherit from the same parent.
As a test:

```
print(make_ancestor() == make_ancestor()) # False
```

Comment: Because they are semantically different classes so I don't like to have a common ancestor, but both contain a complex object for which I implemented the logic in a separate module. I thought it was possible to use a decorator on the class, but also your solution seems interesting